# Do customers ever access data from a company or is everything they access just information?

Tags: data-request

I'm not sure if this is the place for this sort of question but it seemed more relevant than stack overflow. Please let me know if there is somewhere better suited to it!

I'm trying to answer a question I've been given along the following lines:

"If you're a digital services company that provides services to consumers for example, what do customers access in the form of data from the company?"  In other words, "Do customers ever access data from a company or is everything they access just information?"

I can only think of them accessing information, everything they access either though online accounts or via post would be in the form of information? As they would never understand just data. Am I along the right lines for this or way off?

Edit:
This is in a information systems perspective. e.g a customers account number is obviously a piece of data but to them wouldn't it be classed as information? as being data it's just a random set of numbers to them not specifically an account number?

Comment: What is this context for this question? Is this an interview question?

Comment: It's a coursework question. I understand the difference between the two but it seems like customers will never need to touch data directly?

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. What is a digital services company? I think you need to give more context or reformulate.

Comment: okay, think of it as just in general then. Do customers ever access data from a company or is everything they access just information?

Comment: That actually gets into some rather deep semantic and philisophical questions about what is 'data' vs. 'information'.  If you ask someone from computer science, everything binary is data.  In the hard sciences, data is something that can be used to support an argument.   In library & information science, there's a relationship between data, information & knowledge that makes this question particularly confusing.

Comment: I agree, everything hinges on what your professor thinks is the difference between `data` and `information.` Maybe if you said what kind of class it was, someone could say something like in X discipline, data and information mean this, and on that basis....

Comment: This is in a information systems perspective. e.g a customers account number is obviously a piece of data but to them wouldn't it be classed as information? as being data it's just a random set of numbers to them not specifically an account number?

Comment: Repeating your question again did not clarify at all. Perhaps you can explain how you define "data" and "information". Can something be both "data" and "information" at the same time? Why is a distinction important and how do you distinguish between the two terms?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the question distinguishes between "information" which the customer receives, and "data" which is how the company itself internally organizes and manages the "information" product it delivers. Might be better termed "digital products" and "product management information/data."

An example would be Netflix, which delivers information in the form of streaming media to customers but customers never see the data that Netflix uses internally to manage and deliver the steaming media.

Regardless of the type of digital product delivered, even if it something like raw demographics data, the company will always have data for internal use that the customers never see. From the IT perspective, there would be compartmentalized systems and likely functional units, one which concentrates on product delivery and one that concentrates on internal operations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty difficult question to answer, since so much depends on how you define ambiguous words, particularly 'data', 'information', and 'digital services.'

However, there are many businesses that sell what I think of as bulk data. For example:

- Synergos
- InfoUSA
- Factual
- various bulk geocoders
- various bulk address standardization services